# JavaScript Prime Number Search Infinite Recursion

Tags: javascript

I've been tackling different coding challenges all day and for some reason I'm stuck on something I thought would be relatively easy. I am trying to create a JS function that takes a number as input and finds that nth prime number (e.x. primesearch(4) would give you 11 as it's the 4th prime number [excluding 2]). I've been trying to debug for hours now and I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop where something in my nested while loop isn't working and I can't figure out why. I'd appreciate if you could take a look at it...I'm assuming there's either something obvious I've been missing or maybe my logic is totally off.

Incase it's not clear, primepoint is the pointer that's incremented when checking for prime numbers, primesqr is the squareroot of primepoint (since that's the highest value you need to check for) and primearray is where the primes are meant to be stored.

Thanks!

```js
//Number being checked
var primepoint = 2;
//Sqr of number being checked
var primesqr = 0;
//Array for prime storage
var primearray = [0];
//Function for prime search at nth value
var primesearch = function(nth) {
  var nth = nth;
  while (primearray.length <= nth + 1) {
    primesqr = Math.sqrt(primepoint)
    if (primepoint % 2 != 0) {
      console.log("entered if")
      var divis = false;
      while (divis = false) {
        for (i = 2; i <= primesqr; i++) {
          if (primepoint % i == 0) {
            primepoint++;
            divis = true;
          } else if (i == primesqr) {
            primearray.push(primepoint);
            console.log("prime found")
            primepoint++;
            divis = true;
          }
        }
      }

    } else {
      primepoint++;
    }
    console.log(primepoint)
  }
}
primesearch(4)
```

Comment: Step through the code in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: `var nth = nth;` is redundant as *nth* is created as a local variable by being included in the parameter list as if it was declared.

Comment: `while (divis = false)` is an assignment, not an equality test (and will always evaluate to `false`).

Comment: RobG could I fix this with == instead of =?

Comment: Conditional operators are always `==, ===, <=, >=, >, <. !=, or !==` Oh yeah, and ternary `var x=(cond)? y : z`

Comment: I don't see how your code is expected to work; could you add a english/pseudocode description of your algorithm?  In particular, I don't understand the use of primepoint or why primearray is never read from only added to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of things with your code:
-`while (divis = false)` should be while `(divis === false)`;

-You continue to loop until your array's length is less than the number of primes, which is fine. However you only push it when (i == primesqr)` which you only increment on it not having a remainder.

-There are some logic flaws as well. You only check to see if prime point is even, not a prime...

I tried this one not too long ago, here is my solution to it:
(I'm not excluding 2)

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/kapale/1/edit?js,console)

```
function primeTester (n) {
  if(n === 2) {
    return true;
  }
  if(n < 2 || n%2 === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  for(var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i+=2) {
    if(n%i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function n(num) {
  var arr = [];
  var j = 2;
  while (arr.length < num) {
    if (primeTester(j)) {
      arr.push(j);
    }
    j++;
  }
  return arr.pop();
}
```

Comment: edited my answer, should have worked on that before submitting, thanks

Comment: I will look into your tips and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for the help, Jordan!